# Show that the stereographic projection is an homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry

I want to show that $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$f(x,y) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)$$
is a parameterization.

My definition of parameterization is immersion that is a homeomorphism over its image.

I can show that $Df$ is injective when $x,y \neq 0$ or only one of them is $0$. My problem is when $x = y = 0$. In the case of $x = y = 0$, seems that $Df$ is not injective so, should I consider $\Bbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}^2$? I'm not sure about that, because I think that in this case, we must find an homeomorphism between $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $S^2 - \{(0,0,1)\}$. I appreciate any help.

**EDIT.**
I found
$$Df(x,y) = \frac{2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1+y^2-x^2 & 1+x^2-y^2\\
-2xy & -2xy\\
-2x & -2y
\end{array}\right).$$
If, $x = y = 0$, then I cannot conclude that $Df$ is injective.

Comment: It seems to me that $f$ maps $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^2 - \{(0,0,-1)\}$, not $S^2 - \{(0,0,1)\}$. After all, $\frac{1-(0^2+0^2)}{1+0^2+0^2}=1,$ so $f(0,0) = (0,0, 1).$  Perhaps you should show your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake somewhere. Let $r^2=x^2+y^2.$ Then

$$f(x,y)=(1+r^2)^{-1}(2x,2y,1-r^2).$$

We find

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-(1+r^2)^{-2}2x(2x,2y,1-r^2) + (1+r^2)^{-1}(2,0,-2x)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-(1+r^2)^{-2}2y(2x,2y,1-r^2) + (1+r^2)^{-1}(0,2,-2y).$$

At $(0,0),$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (2,0,0),\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=(0,2,0).$$

These two vectors are linearly independent, hence $Df(0,0)$ is injective.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The image of this map is $\{(u,v,w) \neq (0,0,1):u^{2}+v^{2}+w^{2}=1\}$.  Simple algebra will help you to compute the inverse explicitly. Once you compute the inverse it will be clear that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Kavi. But I don't know if it helps me with the injectivity of $Df$. I can show that $Df(x,y)$ is injective for every $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, but I'm stuck at the point $(0,0)$. If necessary, I can write my calculations.